# Need to create a graph/report using any report engine for SQL database

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have a table created in my SQL DB with data filled. I want to create a report out of it with visual display (Graphs). If anyone has done it, please can you suggest if there are any free report engines and how to proceed with my work? I have found one report engine in inetsoft but it is paid.

I am using a MySQL Database. My table layout has 4 columns where 2 areintegers and 2 are strings. I'm using Eclipse, Java, Selenium on a Mac as development environment. I tried with all possible keywords in internet to get freeware to plot the graphs. But I did not find any.

I have explored many reporting tools which are free (data vision) but they don't support graph/chart display.

One more requirement is that the report should be dynamic. that means user is going to select parameters from the report window, which type of chart he wants to display etc. So can anyone help me find such a free tool?

Comment: Some additional detail would be very helpful - things like "What database engine are you using?", "What does your table look like (schema)",  and "What development tools are you using?".

Comment: MySQL database i am using. Table consists of 4xn data. out of 4, 2 are integers and 2 are strings. development tools used are eclipse, java, selenium + MAC. hope this data will help you to help me. :-0

Answer (score 1):

[myDBR](http://mydbr.com/) offers free version and extensive set of available charts in the web reporting system. Supports MySQL, MS SQL Server and Sybase (both ASE and SQL Anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

If you have MS sql server, sql server reporting services is free.

Comment: Will it works for MAC? pls can you share any examples link if you have. Suggest me if there are any other free tools available for plotting graphs for report and all.. by reading data from sql.